# swipe gesture toolbar

Tags: ios, toolbar, gesture, swipe

for my App I need to recognize a swipe gesture on a toolbar to change the items on the toolbar. So I can scroll through the toolbar.

I want to develop for iOS 5.0 or higher with XCode 4.3

I only found out how to change viewController by using swipeGestures.

Can you help me?

Comment: Who is the other one?! **In the end there can be only one..**

Comment: @JackyBoy: You'll never defeat John skeet...

Comment: I tried dragging the swipe gesture onto the toolbar (in storyboard) and tried to link it with the toolbar again. But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)swipeDidHappen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe {
        [self setToolbarItems:secondArray animated:YES];
}
```

Should fade out/in some new items great.  Note that the toolbar must be the one supplied by UINavigationController.  To hook it up, create one in code, and use `[[self toolbar]addGestureRecognizer:gesture];`.  `secondArray` is an array of UIBarButtonItems, which must be made programmatically (as far as I know, you cannot storyboard an array, nor should you).

Comment: Thanks so far, but how do I connect a Recognizer with this code? The other thing is about the secondArray, how to store ToolBar Items from Storyboard in an array? :/

Comment: UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSwipe:)];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [[self toolbarItems]addGestureRecognizer:gesture];


This is how far I am. But the last expression isn't accepted: "No visible @interface for NSArray declares the selector 'addGestureRecognizer'.

What do I have to do to solve this?

Comment: use `[self toolbar]`, not `[self toolBarItems]`

Comment: Are you showing the toolbar that belongs to the Navigation Controller, or the one you made in the storyboard?

Comment: I'm using a ViewController in StoryBoard.

Comment: But the toolbar specifically:  does it belong to UINavigationController, or did you drag it into your storyboard?

Comment: I dragged it into the storyboard.

Comment: There's your problem.  Trash the one in the storyboard and use `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];` instead.  Place it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: I placed it in viewDidLoad --> no toolbar showing up? :) Wheres the problem?